# Is MessageReceiver supported in Service Bus Topic Triggered Java Azure Function?

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-topics

Basically the title.
Here's my code

```
   @FunctionName("Process")
public void run(@ServiceBusTopicTrigger(
        name = "req",
        topicName = TemplatedConstants.topicName,
        subscriptionName = TemplatedConstants.subscriptionName,
        connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")
                    @BindingName("MessageReceiver") MessageReceiver messageReceiver,  String message, final ExecutionContext context) {
```

I am trying to inject MessageReceiver into the Java Azure Function but I get the following error.

***'com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.MessageReceiver' is not public in 'com.microsoft.azure.servicebus'. Cannot be accessed from outside package***

My goal is to read the message in a 'destructive read' mode instead of the default 'peek lock' mode. I was hoping to call the .complete() method on the MessageReceiver object upon receiving the message right away so the message does not get dead lettered after the lock duration is over.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, non-C# languages in Azure Functions do not support binding to complex language-specific types. You would have to directly use SDK when required.

<s>***But*** you can still achieve "destructive read" (aka [ReceiveAndDelete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-transfers-locks-settlement#receiveanddelete)) by setting the `extensions.serviceBus.messageHandlerOptions.autoComplete` property value to `true` in [`host.json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-output?tabs=csharp#hostjson-settings).</s>

The only other option is using the function execution to pass the message to another function via REST or the likes, and have the triggered function end immediately.

If the sequence number and lock token were available in the [message metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp#message-metadata), technically you should be able to complete the message via the [Service Bus API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/delete-message). But this would be a feature request to expose them as such, not to mention the Service Bus SDKs do not expose a method that uses these parameters to allow completing a message.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I thought the autoComplete property is set to true by default and it will mark the message as complete **after** the function exits (against marking the message as complete immediately after the function starts executing).

Comment: @AshwinPurushotaman Did this answer turn out to be correct? Because my understanding is aligned with your original one.

Comment: @kaqqao Not sure what I meant at the time but that is indeed incorrect.